# Delete empty rows from print output in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm learning python requests and BeautifulSoup. I've managed to write a script that log-in in a site and scraps a table. Here's the code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
table = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class': 'griglia_tab', 'id':'data_table'})[2]
print(table.text)
```

When i run the script i get the desired output but there are a lot of empty rows between the values. How can i delete them and maybe output the values in a proper way?

Comment: Use a list comprehension to filter out entries with `len` less than 1

Comment: It might help to include what the output looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were trying to scrape [this](https://gist.github.com/mrandri19/189388b787afef0749e44cb55a4c072e) page, here's a code that might work. You'll need to use `re` to substitute multiple consecutive newlines with a single newline.

```
print(re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', '\n', table.text.strip()))
```

**Edit:**

Few suggestions to your code:

An `id` attribute will uniquely identify a single table in the page. Since the table you need to print has one, using `'class': 'griglia_tab'` is unnecessary. You can do away with `find_all` as well, and use `find` instead.

So, replace your code to assign to `table` with this:

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id':'data_table'})
```

Comment: I can't use the id attribute because there are multiple tables with the same id. I was able to select that specific tablet only with find_all. Comunque sei italiano per caso?

Comment: @andrea56, ok then you can ignore my suggestion. Did the regex solution work? And, I don't understand your last statement. I don't speak your language.